# Direct URL to item in list, how?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath-forms-services

Sharepoint 2010 & Infopath Form  I want to use a url to go from a web page directly to a specific row using the form for that list

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? It is hard to answer without more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Open the item in your browser and copy the url from the address bar of your browser.

Comment: no a little confusing -  ......./eforms/Lists/TestPreferences/Item/displayifs.aspx?List=7e9bb03f%2Dcae5%2D4e21%2D8d7e%2D9150f9131e77&ID=3&ContentTypeId=0x0100B45F53E47817C74AB2B81715772FC2D6....... I want to dispaly a single form using a unique field (userID) in the parameter string of the url

Comment: You should be able to remove the ContentTypeId and List Query String parameters, leaving the ID parameter without issue.